# direct location using google maps application

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation

```
  // custom function to locate the location to direct using google maps app
  Future<void> openMap(List<CustAddressModel>latitude,longitude) async {
    String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';

    await canLaunchUrlString(googleUrl)
    ? await launchUrlString(googleUrl)
        : throw 'Could not launch google map $googleUrl';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    custLocation();

    }
  }
```

Here i want to custom function openMap() where user can click button to direct the location using google maps app. Location 1 where the seller location i retrieve from database and the location 2 is customer location i retrieve from database also. Now i want to pass the lat and long from both location 1 and 2, so that user can direct to google maps app to direct to seller location

Answer (score 0):

you can use the packege [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and then add following code:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class MapUtils {

  MapUtils._();

  static Future<void> openMap(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';
    if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
      await launch(googleUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open the map.';
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can open google maps in your app just call this method:

```
onTap: () {
   final snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("collectionName").document('docId').get();
  final lat = snapshot.data['latitude'];
  final long = snapshot.data['longitude'];
   MapUtils.openMap(lat, long);
};
```

On iOS you need to do some extra steps is that, write following lines in info.plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Comment: but i want to retrieve the lat and long from firebase

Comment: can you share how you're storing lat and long in firebase

Comment: in my collection field i store latitude: 8.4893, longitude: 329.3920 like that

Comment: nobody help me:(

Comment: I've updated my answer. Checkout that

Comment: is it necessary to use MapUtils? what happen if i dont want to use it?

Comment: you can use without that class as well. Actually, I mentioned that as it's called as a clean structure

Comment: i can direct to google map but when i want to start the direction to the location it errors